# login authentication filter java struts

Tags: java, authentication, filter, struts1

i have a question. How to filter multiple user for login in java struts?

here is my code

```
LoginFilter.java

public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    private FilterConfig config = null;

    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        config = null;
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);

        String cek;
        if(session.getAttribute("idNasabah") != null){
            cek = session.getAttribute("idNasabah").toString();
        }else if(session.getAttribute("idStaff")!= null){
            cek = session.getAttribute("idStaff").toString();
        }else{
            cek = null;
        }

        if(cek== null){
            req.getRequestDispatcher("login.do").forward(request, response);
        }else{
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.config = config;
    }

}
```

and here is the web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>filter.LoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

How to differentiate a role (admin and user). Differentiating pages that can be accessed by the admin and user. because with my code, can only filter if not logged in, while still able to access the admin user directly. For example, I logged in to the admin, then I can still access

/InternetBanking/pembayaranKartuKredit.do?task=CreditCard

anyone can help? thaks :)

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. If you need more complex filtering than simply "you're idNasabah or idStaff" then add it. There are many ways to do this; checking for an annotation, marker interface, method name; using Spring Security; using a map of users/accessible pages, etc etc etc.

Comment: I'm using Struts and filtering class (LoginFilter.java). I want to make a limit for user to access just specified pages based on role.
The problem is, when I haven't logged in, the pages can't be access directly by path,
but if I've logged in, the role can't differentiate which page that I can / cannot access.
For example : I have 2 roles, admin and user. When I logged in using admin role, 
I still can access user's pages directly by path, which is shouldn't be accessed.
How to set the role in web xml or in filtering class? and where should I set it?